# Add member to distribution group using Azure AD API

Tags: node.js, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I want to add a member to a **distribution list**. As apparently I can't do this using Microsoft Graph, I am trying to use Azure AD Graph API. I am using Node.js.

I am able to connect to Azure using the adal-node library. I get a token back, send requests, and get responses. (I can list groups, users, etc.).

I am following the [Add Members documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/Azure/Ad/Graph/api/groups-operations#AddGroupMembers), but I am confused.

1. In the URL, is `object_id` the `id` of the Group to witch I want to add the member?
2. For `myorganization`, I am using the `tennant_id`.
3. Where do I specify the user data? Should I pass that in the `POST`? If so, whats' the format?
4. What is the `$links` in the URL?

Currently, I am doing this:

```
request.post(
  "https://graph.windows.net/TENNANT_ID_HERE/groups/GROUP_ID_HERE/$links/members?api-version=1.6",
  {
    headers: {
      Authorization: "Bearer " + TOKEN_HERE,
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    form: { key: "value" } //should I put my user object here?
  },
  function(err, res, body) {
    if (err) {
      console.log("err: " + err);
    } else {
      console.log("res: " + JSON.stringify(res, null, 3));
    }
  }
);
```

I get the following error:

```
{
  "odata.error": {
    "code": "Request_BadRequest",
    "message": {
      "lang": "en",
      "value":  "A supported MIME type could not be found that matches the 
                content type of the response. None of the supported type(s) 'application/xml, text/xml, 
                application/json;odata=minimalmetadata;streaming=true, application/json;odata=minimalmetadata;
                streaming=false, application/json;odata=minimalmetadata, 
                application/json;odata=fullmetadata;streaming=true, 
                application/json;odata=fullmetadata;streaming=false, 
                application/json;odata=fullmetadata, 
                application/json;odata=nometadata;streaming=true, 
                application/json;odata=nometadata;streaming=false, 
                application/json;odata=nometadata, 
                application/json;streaming=true, 
                application/json;streaming=false, 
                application/json;odata=verbose, 
                application/json' 
                matches the content type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'."
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short/most important answer is that *neither* Microsoft Graph or Azure AD Graph API supports distribution lists. From the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/Azure/Ad/Graph/api/groups-operations#AddGroupMembers):

> **Important**: You can only add members to security groups and mail-enabled security groups.

---

That said, this isn't technically why your call is failing here. Your code is reaching the point where it's failing due to the type of group you're working with. And while it won't help you with managing a distribution list, the following is what is actually happening.

The `form: { key: "value" }` option is telling [request](https://github.com/request/request) to send the payload as a URL Encoded Form (`application/x-www-form-urlencoded`). The API requires the payload be sent as JSON (`application/json`).

To send over JSON, you need to do two things:

1. Set the `json` option to `true`
2. Set the `body` value rather than the `form` value.

The proper code would look something like this:

```
request.post(
  "https://graph.windows.net/{tenant-id}/groups/{group-id}/$links/members?api-version=1.6",
  {
    headers: {
      Authorization: "Bearer " + TOKEN_HERE
    },
    json: true,
    body: JSON.stringify({ url: "https://graph.windows.net/{tenant-id}/directoryObjects/{user-id}" })
  },
  function(err, res, body) {
    if (err) {
      console.log("err: " + err);
    } else {
      console.log("res: " + JSON.stringify(res, null, 3));
    }
  }
);
```

The `$links` parameter in the URI is telling the API that you're providing a link to another resource (in this case, a user record).

Comment: Thank you! But then, is there anyway at all to achieve adding a member to a distribution list via the API? Or any other way other than login into the admin interface and do it manually? My software intends to have name and last name as inputs, and to create the email account and adding it into distribution lists.

Comment: I believe you can do this with Exchange Web Services but I would strongly recommend pivoting away from Distribution Lists and using Unified Groups (aka O365 Groups) instead. They can be configured to act very much like a classic DL by turning on the `autoSubscribeNewMembers` option but they also come with a lot more robust features (not to mention modern API support). Unified Groups is where everything is headed (Teams is built on them as well).

Answer (score 1):

we could add member to a group with AD [graph API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/Azure/Ad/Graph/api/groups-operations#AddGroupMembers).

```
post https://graph.windows.net/{tenantId}/groups/{groupobjectid}/$links/members?api-version=1.6
```

body

```
{
  "url": "https://graph.windows.net/{tenantId}/directoryObjects/{userObjectId}"
}
```

Test it with Postman

[image]